# Pass data through hyperlink to a separate sub form in Survey123

Tags: arcgis-survey123

I have a parent form in survey123 that generates a unique ID when teh form is opened with the calculation: `uuid()` .

This ID is in a field called "inspectionid"

I have subsequent hyperlinks to "subforms" within this parent form. THey are distinctly separate forms that are more detailed inspections of parts of the parent form.  Basically the parent form say "is "X" present? Y/N"  If yes,here's a link to a sebform to describe "X". I've since been asked to link the subform inspection events to the parent form so I'd like to pass that auto generated "inspectionid" value to the subform into a field called "parentinspectionid"

The current hyperlinks are formatted like this and they launch fine (we may want to modify them later to open in the Survey123 app rather than the web app but for now, this is what I'm comparing against.

`<a href="https://arcg.is/abcd123" target="_blank"> Related Subfform</a>`

I've tried this:

`<a href="arcgis-survey123://?itemID=MyFormItemID&field:inspectionid_field_This_form={ParentInspID_field_to_pass_to_Subform}"> Subform Name</a>`

and other variations that were just totally misguided.

But the Survey123Connect preview does not show this as a clickable link but rather as static text so I can't tell if I'm even on the right track.

**Can I format the hyperlink to pass the "inspectionid" from the main form to to the "parentinspectionid" of the sub forms?**

Comment: When you say "subform", do you simply mean another separate/independent Survey123 survey form?  You can call Survey123 surveys with fields pre-filled in their URLs like this:  `arcgis-survey123://?itemID=UniqueSurveyID&field:inspectionid=abcd-1234-efgh-5678&field:SomeOtherField=SomeOtherValue`

Comment: Yes that's the idea of my "subform" but it does not appear to pass the uuid() calculated value to the subform  'arcgis-survey123://?itemID=myformitemid&field:inspectionid={parentinspectionid}'  does not show as a link is the survey123connect preview

Comment: Can you post the full code of the note definition in which you have tried this?  Ie, including the `<a href="...."></a>`.  It may also be worth trying to hard-code a simple `http://` url for starters to make sure that works.